# how to use mongoid nested attributes on my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

My app is a **rails_admin** with **mongoid** working well.

Now I'm trying to use nested attributes on edit form, but I don't know exactly how to do this.

My document is:

```
{
    "_id"     :ObjectId("..."),
    "email"   :"steve@steve.com",
    "name"    :"steve",
    "facebook":{
        "id":12345,
    }
}
```

So, my model is:

```
class User
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name
   field :email
   field :facebook
end
```

So, the problem is:

On the edit form it shows a text field with facebook json content: `{"id":12345}`

How can I use one text field for each sub attribute? I tried something like `field :facebook.id` but it doesn't work.

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried specifying the field types? `field :name, :type => String; field :email, :type => String; field :facebook, :type => Hash` for example.

Comment: what is facebook field data type?

Comment: @muistooshort Setting type as `Hash` it shows a textarea with BSON content

Comment: @RubyOnRails I tried setting as Hash but it shows a textarea with BSON string

Comment: Can you tell me what are you implementing!!! Can you just implement like <% params[:facebook].each do |key,value| %>
<%= value %> <% end %>

Comment: I guess rails-admin doesn't know anything about Mongoid field typed then. Is there any way to tell it how to edit certain things? Is there any useful documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Better is to make a custom field serialization of facebookHash, something similar to

```
class User
   include Mongoid::Document
    field :name
    field :email
    field :facebook, :type => facebookHash
 end
```

If you did not have idea regarding custom field serialization, Have a look at [Custom Fields in MongoId](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/documents.html). Then you can easily create your fields partial on the basis of that model.